# hide() is not working

Tags: jquery

I wanted to hide my second image with jQuery `.hide()` but the method is not working in some cases.

Here's my code:

**jQuery**

```
var one = $('ul li > img')[0];
var two = $('ul li img')[1];
var three = $('ul li img')[2];

$(two).on('click', function(){
  alert('working');
});

two.hide();
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://img.pixland.uz/u13301f281573m.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://img.pixland.uz/u13301f281573m.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://img.pixland.uz/u13301f281573m.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCMX8/)

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery? jQuery does not come from the browser itself.

Comment: You wrapped `two` in a jQuery call for `on` so why not for `hide`?

Comment: jQuery has [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('ul li img')[1]` is a DOM object, not a jQuery object so it doesn't have a `.hide()` method.

You can use this:

```
$('ul li img').eq(1)
```

instead, if you want a jQuery object.

The whole code block would look like this:

```
var one = $('ul li > img').eq(0);
var two = $('ul li img').eq(1);
var three = $('ul li img').eq(2);

two.on('click', function(){
  alert('working');
});

two.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Object named `two` is not a *jQuery* object, it's just a plain *DOM* object. You should either do:

```
var one = $('ul li > img')[0];
var two = $('ul li img')[1];
var three = $('ul li img')[2];

$(two).on('click', function(){
  alert('working');
});

$(two).hide();
```

or do:

```
var one = $('ul li > img').eq(0);
var two = $('ul li img').eq(1);
var three = $('ul li img').eq(2);

$(two).on('click', function(){
  alert('working');
});

two.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var one = $('ul li > img')[0];
var two = $('ul li img')[1];
var three = $('ul li img')[2];

$(two).on('click', function(){
  alert('working');
    $(two).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change in your code is two.hide() to ${two}.hide()

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = $('ul li:eq(0) img');
var two = $('ul li:eq(1) img');
var three = $('ul li:eq(2) img');
```